# Can you add a custom field/column to a SQLFORM.grid?

Tags: web2py

I am trying to use a `SQLFORM.grid()` everything works find however I'm trying to add a new `field` to it. My query is made up of two tables joined together. For example:

```
db.define_table('table1',
    Field('total','integer')
)
db.define_table('table2',
    Field('table1_id','integer'),
    Field('count','integer'),
)

query = (db.table1.id == db.table2.table1_id)

grid = SQLFORM.grid(query,fields=[
    db.table1.total,
    db.table2.count,
    (db.table1.total - db.table2.count) #this doesn't work
    ])
```

So is it possible to add a column that is generated via a math function or not necessarily needed in this case but two values concatenated together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "links" argument:

```
grid = SQLFORM.grid(query, fields=[db.table1.total, db.table2.count],
                    links=[dict(header='Total - Count',
                                body=lambda r: r.table1.total - r.table2.count)])
```

By default, all "links" columns appear on the right. You can change that by setting the "links_placement" argument to either "left" or "both".

Comment: Thanks, I wish this was shown as an example in the book.