# Add a dummy input text to a web2py sqlform.grid in edit or create mode

Tags: web2py

How to add a dummy input text to a web2py [sqlform.grid](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM-grid-and-SQLFORM-smartgrid) in edit or create mode?

This text input should not be bound to the database. It is just needed to fire some javascript functions attached to it, reading and dynamically updating other fields of the sqlform.grid, when in edit or create mode.

It seems that sqlform.grid "links" as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27390762/3866723) do not allow for this use case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Of course using [web2py custom forms](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators?search=custom#Custom-forms) I can achieve it, but if the form has many fields, it is sometimes unpractical. Looking to see if there is a way using the sqlform.grid definition.

Answer (score 0):

The forms in web2py can be manipulated through the server [side DOM](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Server-side-DOM-and-parsing). So you can inject anything you like into those forms. Here is an example from the [manual](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Adding-extra-form-elements-to-SQLFORM).

```
form = SQLFORM(db.yourtable)
my_extra_element = TR(LABEL('I agree to the terms and conditions'),
                      INPUT(_name='agree', value=True, _type='checkbox'))
form[0].insert(-1, my_extra_element)
```

All the DOM helpers can be found [here](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Built-in-helpers).